# Adding two matrix with different dimension

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, multidimensional-array, linear-algebra

Let `A` be a matrix with `[m x n]` elements and `B` another matrix with `[m x n x o]` elements.
Is there any linear algebraic way to add both matrices such that `C = A + B` where `C` will be in `[m x n x o]` without any sort of looping along the `o` dimension?

Example:

Let

A =

```
 1     2     5     6
 1     2     3     4
 1     5     8     9
```

and

B(:,:,1) =

```
 1     1     1     1
 1     1     1     1
 1     1     1     1
```

B(:,:,2) =

```
 1     1     1     1
 1     1     1     1
 1     1     1     1
```

B(:,:,3) =

```
 1     1     1     1
 1     1     1     1
 1     1     1     1
```

C = A + B

C(:,:,1) =

```
 2     3     6     7
 2     3     4     5
 2     6     9    10
```

C(:,:,2) =

```
 2     3     6     7
 2     3     4     5
 2     6     9    10
```

C(:,:,3) =

```
 2     3     6     7
 2     3     4     5
 2     6     9    10
```

Comment: What is the output supposed to look like?

Comment: Please make an example.

Comment: Is this MATLAB or python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is easy to do in Numpy: it will automatically expand A for you.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 5, 8, 9]])
print(a, end='\n\n')

b = np.ones((3, 3, 4), dtype='int32')
print(b, end='\n\n')

c = b + a
print(c)
```

**output**

```
[[1 2 5 6]
 [1 2 3 4]
 [1 5 8 9]]

[[[1 1 1 1]
  [1 1 1 1]
  [1 1 1 1]]

 [[1 1 1 1]
  [1 1 1 1]
  [1 1 1 1]]

 [[1 1 1 1]
  [1 1 1 1]
  [1 1 1 1]]]

[[[ 2  3  6  7]
  [ 2  3  4  5]
  [ 2  6  9 10]]

 [[ 2  3  6  7]
  [ 2  3  4  5]
  [ 2  6  9 10]]

 [[ 2  3  6  7]
  [ 2  3  4  5]
  [ 2  6  9 10]]]
```

For the details on how Numpy handles combining arrays of different shapes please see the Numpy [Broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) docs.

---

That code will work no matter what the contents of `b` are, I just used an array of ones to match your sample data. However, if you just want `c` to be an m x n x o matrix created by expanding `a` and then adding one to all the elements you don't even need to create `b`; you can do this instead:

```
c = np.tile(a, (3, 1, 1)) + 1
```

Answer (score 5):

In MATLAB this can be done using implicit expansion (R2016b onward) or `bsxfun(@plus,...)`.

The following would work in all recent MATLAB versions:

```
C = bsxfun(@plus,A,B);
```

In NumPy, this behavior is known as "broadcasting".

Answer (score 0):

You can just add them, stating the position of the missing (`o`) dimension. Here's a `python` example using `numpy` arrays:

```
import numpy as np

>> arr_a = np.random.rand(2, 2)
array([[ 0.461715  ,  0.57055533],
   [ 0.16992256,  0.93994827]])

>> arr_b = np.random.rand(2, 2, 2)
array([[[ 0.71475233,  0.26140088],
    [ 0.1469756 ,  0.20147053]],

   [[ 0.18321165,  0.46292277],
    [ 0.07598337,  0.51653255]]])
# First generating an array with dimension [m * n * o], quickest to directly copy arr_b
>> arr_c = arr_b.copy()
# Placing array a in the zeroth column of the third dimension
>> arr_c[:, :, 0] += arr_a
array([[[ 1.17646733,  0.26140088],
    [ 0.71753093,  0.20147053]],

   [[ 0.35313422,  0.46292277],
    [ 1.01593163,  0.51653255]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

As Dev-il pointed out, the optimal solutions for MATLAB are: (2016b) use implicit expansion (`C=A+B`), or (2016a and older) use `bsxfun(@plus,A,B)`. However, if you're new to MATLAB then how to use bsxfun may be hard to grasp. A third solution that is simpler (for me) to understand conceptually, but less efficient computationally is to use repmat to expand matrix A to the size of matrix B.

```
C = repmat(A,[1,1,o]) + B
```

Note that using bsxfun or implicit expansion is preferred over using repmat for computational efficiency; I'm only pointing out this option because I had trouble understanding bsxfun when I started with MATLAB.